# Linguagem de programação ADVPL no Stack Overflow

Tags: debate

Trabalhei durante muito tempo como analista de TI de uma empresa que utilizava o sistema ERP PROTHEUS da Microsiga (hoje grupo TOTVS). Durante este período participei da implantação de alguns módulos e também de algumas customizações no sistema.

O ERP Protheus utiliza a linguagem de programação ADVPL para as customizações. Esta linguagem é uma extensão do padrão xBase/clipper de comandos e funções, operadores, estruturas de controle de fluxo e palavras reservadas, contando também com funções e comandos disponibilizados pela TOTVS.

Existe uma infinidade de programadores no Brasil e em outros países que sempre estão buscando informações e ajuda sobre este assunto. Existem sites e blogs sobre o assunto, mas não como o Stack Overflow. Penso que aqui seria um local muito bom para esta comunidade de programadores.

O que vocês acham?

Poderia ser criada uma tag sobre este assunto?

Comment: Existem [duas perguntas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advpl) sobre a linguagem uma dentro do escopo e a outra fora.

Comment: Nesse caso, o Denis poderia dar um tapa [no wiki da tag](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/1496), sugerindo uma edição ;) O "fragmento" neste caso deve dizer brevemente o que é a linguagem e quando usar a tag. O corpo pode ser tão detalhado quando possível, incluindo links para documentação oficial e outros recursos úteis.

Comment: Na minha opinião, perguntas em ADVPL são muito bem vindas. Principalmente dado o grande número de usuários dessa linguagem, como você mesmo menciona. Só pra você não se sentir sozinho, saiba que eu trabalhei na Microsiga há um boooommm tempo atrás. Eu até admito que tenho alguma saudade de ADVPL, embora lembre bem pouco dos detalhes da linguagem (code blocks!). Quem sabe tendo mais perguntas isso reative a minha memória. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Claro! Os programadores de ADVPL, ou de qualquer outra linguagem, são muito bem-vindos aqui. Eu só recomendaria direcionar os novatos para o [tour](/tour) do site, já que o funcionamento do site às vezes causa estranhamento.

Sobre a tag, primeiro é preciso haver pelo menos uma pergunta sobre a linguagem. Tags sem perguntas relacionadas são destruídas automaticamente pelo sistema. Você pode criar uma pergunta, colocar as tags relevantes já disponíveis, e sinalizar para que um moderador crie a tag ADVPL.